# Creating a Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

In developer.android training there is an explnation on how to create Navigation Drawer  http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html.
there is a sample app in this tuturial --> http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/NavigationDrawer.zip .

in eclipse you can also create Navigation Drawer  (file->new->android application project....->Navigation Drawer activity).
in eclipse Navigation Drawer activity there is a NavigationDrawerFragment class , but in the sample app they use ListView

my question is why the sample app and eclipse Navigation Drawer activity are so diffrent (Although they have the same functionality)?
what is the use of NavigationDrawerFragment class? why to use Fragement ( instead of  ListView like in the sample app)?

Answer (score 0):

I never work with NavigationDrawerFragment. I think its hard or etc. If you want real Navigation Drawer go to this link=
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: maybe for you yes but for me no

Comment: 10x, unlike eclipse Navigation Drawer activity and  NavigationDrawerFragment class - the sample app is much more understandable  - so I wondered what is the use of NavigationDrawerFragment?

Answer (score 0):

Here you have and updated [Nav Drawer implementation sample according to Material Design](https://github.com/Sottti/MaterialDesignNavDrawer). From Google IO 2015 it's recommended to use the [Android Support Design library](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) that will make your life easy.